# Find probability of sequence conversion for sub sequences and their combinations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, statistics

I have data that looks like this

```
sno     Sequence                                conversion 
1       A-B-C-D-E-B-A                                1
2       A-B-C-D                                      0
3       A-B-C-D                                      1
4       D-E-H-I-A                                    0
5       Z                                            0
6       A-Z                                          0
7       F-E-T-H-S-A-T-J-F-E-D-E-S-X-G-N-N-K-L-D      1
8       H-S-A-T-J-F-E                                0
```

The data contains Sequences that may start and end with anything randomly. At the end of the sequence, there is a flag that says conversion. It's '1' if the Sequence converts and 0 if the sequence doesn't. I want to find out how individual parts in sequence influence conversion by finding the conditional probability of conversion of each sequence part or combination of these individual sub-sequence.
For example, if A is encountered in the sequence conversion probability of the whole sequence goes up by 2%.
If A-B-C is encountered in a combination then the probability of conversion goes up by 13%
If Z-A is encountered, the probability of conversion goes up by 8%.

How do I make a table like this -

```
Sno   Sub-sequence    probabilty_of_conversion 
1         A                2%
2         B                1%
3         C                4%
......
4         A-B-C            13%
5.        Z-A              8%
```

Comment: how do you calc those probabilities? I mean how do you come to "A" -> 2 ? you count the numbers of ocurrences in every word? and divided by the number of characters in all words? what about 2-long sequences? you count the number of pairs? and so?=

Comment: in the example above, whenever A-B-C-D is encountered, the probability of conversion is 50% as in this data out of two times it was encountered, only once it converted.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [itertools module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), specifically the section on "combinatoric iterators", since if "A-B-C" converts you want to increase the probability for "A", "A-B", "B-C" and "A-B-C", if I understand your problem correctly.

Comment: There is nothing `bayesian` about this question (removing tag). Question requests code to compute conditional *frequencies*, which is simply `statistics`.

Comment: Let's talk about `A`, this is found in data sno [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8], and only converted on [1, 3, 7] so the conversion probability of `A` is 3/7 or 42.86%. Is this the right way to calculate the probability of a sub?

Comment: Thats correct @Fredy
I am trying to find how much conversion is influenced by A

Comment: Provide the expected output with the correct probabilities according to the given example data. The current expected output with made-up numbers doesn't tell us much, and only generates more confusion. The same goes for the description of the output "For example, if A is encountered in the sequence conversion probability of the whole sequence goes up by 2%. If A-B-C is ...". This doesn't apply to the given example, nor does it explain the logic behind those values.

Comment: The `Sno` column in the output isn't clear to me either, since the same `Sub-sequence` may correspond to multiple `sno`. Don't you want to aggregate the different `sno` into a single list for each `Sub-sequence`? Or do you want each (`sno`, `Sub-sequence`, `probabilty_of_conversion`) in a different row, which means repeating the same `Sub-sequence` and `probabilty_of_conversion` multiple times? Or is the `Sno` in the output just the `Sub-sequence` number, which is not related to the `sno` of the input data?

Comment: @kshitij First question, is A-Z same as Z-A? Secondly, if I think about given data and Bayes theorem, then I imagine something like this 

`P(1|A) = (P(A|1) P(1)) / P(A) = 0.25`

P(1|A) will give you given A in the sequence, what is the probability that the sequence converts. If this seems promising to you, please write back and I will get back with a python code that can do for all sub sequences.

Comment: Hi @Triloknath, so A-Z is not same as Z-A as the sequence order matter here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Something like this:**

```
import pandas as pd


# input data
input_ = [('A-B-C-D-E-B-A', 1), ('A-B-C-D', 0), ('A-B-C-D', 1),
        ('D-E-H-I-A', 0), ('Z', 0), ('A-Z', 0),
        ('F-E-T-H-S-A-T-J-F-E-D-E-S-X-G-N-N-K-L-D', 1),
        ('H-S-A-T-J-F-E', 0)]
input_ = pd.DataFrame(input_, columns=['sequence', 'conversion'])


# generate sub-sequences
def get_sub_sequences(sequence):
    total = len(sequence)
    for i in range(total):
        for j in range(i+1, total+1):
            yield sequence[i:j]

            
# populate sub-sequences
sub_sequences = []
for sequence in data.sequence:
    for sub_sequence in get_sub_sequences(sequence.split('-')):
        sub_sequence = '-'.join(sub_sequence)
        if sub_sequence not in sub_sequences:
            sub_sequences.append(sub_sequence)
sub_sequences = sorted(sub_sequences, key=len)
            

# populate probabilities
probabilities = []
for sub_sequence in sub_sequences:
    values = []
    for row in data.itertuples():
        if sub_sequence in row.sequence:
            values.append(row.conversion)
    probability = round((sum(values) / len(values) * 100))
    probabilities.append(f'{probability}%')


# output data
output = pd.DataFrame(zip(sub_sequences, probabilities),
                      columns=['sub_squence', 'probability'])
output
```

---

**Expected Output:**

[image]

Comment: This answer looks good! I do have a quick question. This is not very efficient for a large dataset, is there any way we can use parallel processing to process the data ?